# Is there an efficient algorithm to find the number of k-length paths (NOT walks) in an undirected and unweighted graph in adjacency matrix form?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I'm aware that the number of k-length walks between two vertices can be found by finding the kth power of the adjacency matrix, but walks include the traversal of a single edge multiple times in the calculation.

EDIT: I only want to *count* them not compute them, preferably using matrix algebra. I could do a modified DFS, but thats less efficient than matrix math.

Comment: Not by using matrix multiplication techniques, since they allow to detect `k`-lengths walks in the matrix. Do you need to know the number of such paths (i.e to count them), or do you also need to compute and return these paths ? The 2 problems are very different.

Comment: @m.raynal I only want to count them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, there is no known way to accomplish this. One way to see this is that if you pick k to be the number of nodes in the graph, then you are asking for the number of Hamiltonian paths in the graph. However, the question of determining whether a graph contains a Hamiltonian path is a canonical **NP**-complete problem, and unless **P** = **NP** there's no polynomial-time algorithm for it.

Stated differently - the Hamiltonian path problem reduces to your problem in polynomial time. That makes your problem **NP**-hard, which means there's no known polynomial-time algorithm for it.